# What model should I use to predict the winner on a card game?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, prediction

I want to do a program to predict the chances of each player to win a match in a card game.

**Explanation of the game:** It is a card game with 50 cards and each player builds a deck with 10 of them. They play using only the ten cards that they choose and there is only one player wins.

I have a dataset with a lot of examples of this card game, so I want to build a model with this data and create a program where you have to input the two decks chosen and you will be able to see the percentage of winning of each player.

I am a bit lost on what I have to use, maybe neural networs?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You forgot to explain how the game works!

Comment: I think that it isn`t important. Its a skill game like clash royale, but I want to know who has more chances to win in order to the deck and regardless of each player's ability.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share **YOUR** findings.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a full coverage of all possible games, you need to check if similar hands lead to similar probabilities. Otherwise any prediction you will make using machine learning will miserably fail. This is highly dependent on the rules.

I am afraid there is no free lunch.